# Why isn't "proper" spelt "propper"?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

A work colleague and I were bickering over why *proper* only has one p. We need help.

There are lots of words that end in the sounds /ɒpər/, but they are all spelled with *-opper*, with two p’s:

> Chopper
>   Shopper
>   Stopper
>   Copper
>   Popper
>   Hopper

There is only one word that ends in /ɒpər/ that doesn’t have two p’s there: **proper**.

Why is this? Why is *proper* different from the rest?

Comment: Because French and German are different languages.  A propper is somebody who props.

Comment: @tchrist Okay, my colleague just said "AHA! But how come it cant be spelt the same but have two meanings!?" (Homonyms)

Comment: I'm sorry, but your cant is unintelligible to me.

Comment: Because that's the propper way to spell it?  (Do note that, with the exception of "copper", all your examples are of a short word with "er" added, and there is a "rule" in English that when a short word ending in a consonant has "er" appended that the consonant is doubled.  But "proper" is not the word "prop" with "er" added.)

Comment: @HotLicks That has helped us both greatly! Though my colleague now asks "Ah but now explain why copper has two p's!"

Comment: @Slopax That's why there are the quotes around "rule".

Comment: @HotLicks Oh no! After telling my colleague this he says "OH SO WE'VE WON THEN? We've broken the English language! How do we fix this newly found problem?" where can we find out more about this rule?

Comment: There are hundreds of such "rules" in English.  They are really just "guidelines" for spelling and pronunciation -- they're *usually* correct and can help you spell a word you've never seen written down or pronounce a word you've never heard spoken.  They can easily lead you astray, especially if you don't apply them with some judgement.  But you can't really work with English without being aware of at least a few of them.

Comment: English spelling is a tangled mess of ‘rules’ (in inverted commas) and **exceptions** (in bold). That’s just the way the cookie crumbles. In Latin, the o was long and the p was short, and since Latin only denotes length in consonants, one o and one p made sense. In French, vowel length was no longer phonemic, so the o was shortened. In English, they just kept spelling it how the French did, though they did eventually decide that _propre_ didn’t look as nice and English as _proper_. It has been spelt in tons of ways historically, though: the OED lists no less than 22 (plus three that are →

Comment: → just errors of transcription or typos), including _propper_, _proppre_, _prapper_, and _proppir_ with a double p.

Comment: (And the specific rule I cited above is just a "short form" of a more lengthy and precise version that I learned in 3rd grade and quickly forgot.)

Comment: Verb: cope, a person who copes would be, if such a word existed, a **coper** not a "copper" although it's slang for a police officer because catching a person committing an illegal act is (also) to [*cop*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cop_2) someone

Comment: aha a [coper](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/coper) is British for a horsedealer. So now you can also ask why is that spelt with only one p, along with piper, moper, and wiper.

Comment: @Mari-LouA But a _coper_ has a long o, which fits with the general guideline-rule common in many Germanic languages that in stressed syllables, ⟨VC⟩ (vowel + single consonant) indicates /VːC/ (long vowel + consonant), whereas ⟨VCC⟩ (vowel + plus double consonant) indicates /VC/ (short vowel + consonant). _(Im)proper_ and _opera_ are indeed the only words I can think of with ⟨oper⟩ that violate this rule, with ⟨oper⟩ reflecting not /oʊpər/ but /ɒpər/ (excepting words in ⟨ooper⟩ /uːpər/ and recent, non-assimilated loans like _Staatsoper_).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ack.  I'm not asking a question, it was just for fun.

Comment: 'Proper' **is** spelled with two Ps! ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: there are also various other words based on Latin opus/operis with trisyllabic shortening like "opera": operative, cooperate etc.

Answer (score 6):

Copper comes from Old English, where it was spelled *coper*. It was probably spelled with two p's in Early Modern English because it was a short vowel, and there was a tendency to double consonants after a short vowel.

Proper comes from French *propre*, and before then from Latin *proprius*. It was probably spelled with one p in Early Modern English because there was a tendency to stick closely to Latin spellings (e.g. *debt*, which never was pronounced with a /b/ in English, but which had the 'b' added in Early Modern English because it originally came from Latin *debitum*.)

As the comments noted, all of the others come from a one-syllable word with the suffix *-er* added. The rule (simplified) is to double the consonant after a short vowel when you add the suffix *-er*.